# iCalendar parse from url (http)

Tags: ruby

I know how to parse a ICS file:

```
  # Open a file or pass a string to the parser
  cal_file = File.open("single_event.ics")

  # Parser returns an array of calendars because a single file
  # can have multiple calendars.
  cals = Icalendar.parse(cal_file)
```

But I have to parse a ICS from a http url (e.g. http://test.com/events.ics).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you're looking for?

```
require 'net/http'
cal_file=(Net::HTTP.get 'test.com', '/single_event.ics')

cals = Icalendar.parse(cal_file)
```